Tabulate frequency of elements within a matrix row
Data
Consider the following matrix.
set.seed(1)
base <- letters[1:4]
mmm <- matrix(sample(base, size=20, replace=TRUE), nrow=4)
print.table(cbind(base, "|", data=mmm))
#      base            
# [1,] a    | a b b a b
# [2,] b    | d a b a b
# [3,] c    | c c c a b
# [4,] d    | a c c b c

Expected output
Matrix indexed by base x base.
 |  a b c d
a|  2 3 0 0
b|  2 2 0 1
c|  1 1 3 0
d|  1 1 3 0

Element (x,y) contains n if y occurs n times in row x.
Or a list of triplets
a,a,2
a,b,3
b,a,2
...

Update
If NA's are involved, for example mmm[2,1] <- NA, then
table(base[row(mmm)], mmm, useNA="ifany")
#   mmm
#    a b c <NA>
#  a 2 3 0    0
#  b 2 2 0    1
#  c 1 1 3    0
#  d 1 1 3    0


With table:
table(rep(base, ncol(mmm)), mmm)
#>    mmm
#>     a b c d
#>   a 2 3 0 0
#>   b 2 2 0 1
#>   c 1 1 3 0
#>   d 1 1 3 0


A shorter version might be t(table(mmm, base[row(mmm)]))

Or table(base[row(mmm)], mmm) if we're code-golfing.

yes, sure, that looks great!

very nice indeed!

Since mmm is a matrix, we can try using apply :
lvls <- sort(unique(c(mmm)))
t(apply(mmm, 1, \(x) table(factor(x, lvls))))

#     a b c d
#[1,] 2 3 0 0
#[2,] 2 2 0 1
#[3,] 1 1 3 0
#[4,] 1 1 3 0

